# Partially select checkbox with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way using Javascript and HTML(5) to make a checkbox be partially selected, like the checkboxes in a program installation menu when you select only some of the sub options?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by 'partially select would you make it more clear.

Comment: @kassens answer does exactly what I was talking about. Partially select meant like in program installation menus when you only select some of the sub option, the parent option checkbox isn't checked or unchecked, but just filled in solid, which I would described as partially selected.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

HTML5 [defines](https://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#dom-htmlinputelement-indeterminate) the `indeterminate` boolean property.

I've tested it only in the latest Safari, Chrome, and Firefox. They all support the indeterminate state.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5tpXc/

**Edit:** Note that this wont work with older browsers and *maybe* not with current versions of IE. You'd need to rely on hacks as described in other answers here if you want to support all browsers.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about that!

Comment: I was hoping there was something html 5 that took care of this, figure html 4 wouldn't. It's for a javascript program that we will be using internally, and my organizations computer management policy forces everyone to have firefox( but not to use it, they just have to have it.) Either way, it's for the network department, so I'm not worried about supporting IE. Thanks for the help!

Comment: BTW, I opened your fiddle in IE9, and it displayed the indeterminate state correctly

Comment: Actually checkbox indeterminate was a Microsoft-ism before it was standardised: it works fine back to IE6 at least. FF3.6+ is reliable too, but I'm seeing problems on other browsers.

Comment: I like this answer. If you're trying to implement a "select all" checkbox, the solution will look something like this:

`$('.all-check').prop('checked', false);` // You still want to be able to reselect all immediately
`$('.all-check').prop('indeterminate', true);` // You no longer know whether all are selected

Answer (score 4):

Nope. You would have to make a custom checkbox graphic and fake it.

**Edit:** Refer to [@Kassen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269342/partially-select-checkbox-with-javascript/6269487#6269487) for a way to have partially checked boxes in HTML5-compliant browsers.

Comment: For modern browsers this is not true, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269342/partially-select-checkbox-with-javascript/6269487#6269487).

Answer (score 4):

HTML checkboxes (that is, `input` elements of type `checkbox`) don't have a third state (partially checked).  So no, there is no direct way to do this.

What you'd probably have to do is make a custom checkbox-looking image and bind to its various events (click, for example) to store its current "state" in a `hidden` form field via JavaScript.  You may run into a number of issues with this approach, though.

For example, keyboard navigation of the form may not be possible for this particular element.  (Can one tab to an image and send it keyboard events?  I'm not sure.)

Additionally, you could try manipulating custom attributes on a checkbox element via JavaScript to store a third state.  But the rendering of the element itself has no visual indicator of something like that.  You could probably manipulate its style (color, background color, border color, etc.) to try to mimic the visual behavior.  But you may not be able to achieve the exact visual style that you're using for reference.

It's certainly an interesting prospect, and I'm intrigued enough that I may try to implement something like this in the near future.  But with a native checkbox element, it's not possible.  It has only two states.

**Edit:** Refer to [@kassens' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269342/partially-select-checkbox-with-javascript/6269487#6269487) for doing this in HTML5.  If you're limited to previous versions of HTML for any reason, then it's going to have to be a hack as described here.  But if you can rely on users supporting HTML5, then it looks like native support is there.